# Constant string plus regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

i just want to check if a line starts with one constant expression plus a number

Then it has discriminate among lines like thesee

```
line blablabla
line1 blablabla
line2 blablablaxag
line3 askdjfoqwuerulksdfjl
...
```

It is probably easy but i ve been trying with different possibilities and still does not work

My tries

```
if str.startswith('line'+'[0-9]')
```

or

```
if str.startswith('line'+'/d')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with without regex using `startswith` and [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
s = "line3 askdjfoqwuerulksdfjl"
if s.startswith("line") and len(s) > 4 and s[4].isdigit():
    print("Found")
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/RzZdNk)

It is possible because your `line` is a constant expression. The `and len(s) > 4` check is necessary to make sure there is at least 1 character after `line`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.match`

```
re.match('line' + r'\d', st)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your sample input there should be a whitespace character that separates the line number prefix from the rest of the line. The following regex pattern will match strings that start with "line", are followed by one or more digits, and that are followed by a whitespace character or end of line.

```
import re

for str in 'line blablabla', 'line1 blablabla', 'line222', 'line12 blablablaxag', 'line12f blablablaxag', 'no line':
    if re.match(r'line\d+(\W|$)', str):
        print str
```

**Output**

```
line1 blablabla
line222
line12 blablablaxag
```

Note that the first str is excluded because it starts with line, but is not followed by a number. The 4th string is excluded because it starts with line followed by a number, but there is a non-digit before the whitespace.

If strings starting with "line" but not followed by a number are valid (the first string from your sample), then you could change the pattern to `r'line\d*(\W|$)'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.findall` to get every line (and the content) that starts with your criteria

```
>>> re.findall('line\d.*', s)
['line1 blablabla',
 'line2 blablablaxag',
 'line3 askdjfoqwuerulksdfjl']
```

If you just want the lines and numbers

```
>>> re.findall('line\d', s)
['line1', 'line2', 'line3']
```